# Folder permissions with cp --parents doesn't allow to copy another file

Tags: permissions, cp

Scenario:
with a script run by a normal user I want to copy several files, and replicate the dir structure. For example:

```
cp --parents /lib/libacl.so /tmp/my_root/
cp --parents /lib/libc.so.6 /tmp/my_root/
```

Expected result: first `cp`, creates /tmp/my_root/lib and puts libacl.so in there. Second `cp` puts libc.so.6 in /tmp/my_root/lib.

The problem is that the first `cp` creates /tmp/my_root/lib with the following permissions: `dr-xr-xr-x.`, so the second `cp` fails with Permission denied.

Of course, if I run the script as root everything works fine.

One solution could be create the dir first and then copy the file, so the dir will have the proper permissions, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this, maybe some flag of `cp`? I checked the man but didn't find anything.

Comment: I suppose that the user who does the `cp --parents` cannot write in the `/lib` directory too. The `/tmp/myroot/lib` directory has the same rights as the `/lib` directory.

Comment: Right, the user cannot write in the `/lib`. So the solution is create the folder first, and then copy the file. I cannot use `cp --parents` in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see a solution with `cp`. You can use `rsync` to do the same
sort of copies, and it also creates a non-writeable `lib` dir, but
it is capable of then adding new files to the dir. Your commands become:

```
rsync -LR /lib/libacl.so /tmp/my_root/
rsync -LR /lib/libc.so.6 /tmp/my_root/
```

The `-R` preserves the directory structure. I added `-L` so that symbolic
links are followed, as that seems to be what `cp` does, though usually this
is not what is wanted. You can add `-a` to preserve permissions and timestamps
(and owner/group if root).

rsync is often used to copy files over the network, but it is
a very versatile command.

---

If you dont have rsync, some other commands which copy files, but
create a *writeable* dir, are `tar` and `cpio`:

```
tar cf - /lib/libc.so.6 | tar -C /tmp/my_root/ -xf -
```

Or use `chf` to follow links. For cpio:

```
ls /lib/libc.so.6 | cpio -pd /tmp/my_root/
```

with -L to follow links.

Comment: The answer is correct and works. However, I cannot use it since in some machines (Solaris) I've found that rsync is not installed. Nevertheless, the solution is correct.

Comment: You probably know about tar and cpio, but I added them as alternatives, as they recreate the directory structure, but keep them writeable. Really need to be wrapped into a small shell script, though.